# Rejected edit question

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I've just gone to edit a question and noticed my last was rejected here: [Help solving differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167418/help-solving-differential-equation)

The reason given was that it conflicted with a subsequent edit, but from that link the subsequent edit seems exactly the same as my own. Am I still seeing my own edit or is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 7):

You were rejected because someone with a rep $\geq 2k$ or the OP was editing as well prior to you submitting your edit.

[image]

Comment: I see from your duplicate posting that the convention is for 2k+ users' edits always to supersede an edit of a poster below 2k. You've answered my question, but I'm not 100% sure I agree with that.

Comment: @MikeMiller that is incorrect. Users greater don't supersede. Did you read the answer? It has to do with when you start and finish.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: Since you have to wait for approval, if a 2k+ user finish a min after you (who started around the same time), you will be rejected since they don't need approval. However, if you start and no one starts at the same time as you, you lock them out of editing.

Comment: Not to get into a discussion if it's not appropriate for comments, but I see the merit of allowing 2k+ users to be trusted, but I also think if it's the case that a lower user has finished an edit before a 2k+ user - the 2k+ user should be able to review the other user's edit and decide.

Comment: @MikeMiller you only have to suffer through it for another 960rep points and other users will be on the receiving end of your simultaneous edits.

Comment: That's another 2 years with my interactions!

Comment: I may be the oddball here in thinking that automatically applied edits should be permitted at something higher than 2k+ rep. That is one of the most powerful privileges I think. I'm surprised the bar isn't set higher, but I won't complain. :)

Comment: @crash it is mainly to stop spammers or people who would do harm with their edits. Not many of them will stick around solely to earn 2000 rep inorder to be destructive.